# getting cstdio errors despite it not being included? (Visual Studio)

Tags: c, visual-studio, cstdio

I'm trying to compile a C program in Visual Studio 2019, I have 'Compile As' set to 'Compile as C Code (/TC)' and cstdio is not included anywhere in my project, yet it still gives me cstdio errors

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cstdio(33,1): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'std'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cstdio(33,1): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cstdio(33,1): error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\cstdio(91,1): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
```

Comment: There is no `cstdio` in C, you are probably trying to compile C++ with a C compiler, which is not going to work.

Comment: @Pablo as stated in the post, I have it set to compile as C, it is C code, cstdio is not included anywhere in the project